# How to make a the bar heights of a horizontal bar chart in Matplotlib constant?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have to create a horizontal bar chart with variable amounts of data in the Y-Axis.

The problem is, the more / less Y Axis data there is, the bar heights shrink / expand to fill the figure.

How do I configure Matplotlib to expand /shrink the plot depending on the amount of data I have instead of shrinking the bars to fit in the figure?

An example would be this image from another answer on this site: [image: barh plot]

If I had less items in the Y Axis, the bars will 'grow' to fill the figure. If I have more, the height of the bars will shrink so all the data can fit within the figure.

I'd prefer to configure matplotlib to get a taller image when there is more data, or a shorter image when there is less data, but the height of the bars remain the same. I hope my description of the problem is clear.

Comment: You're looking for the `figsize` argument, which you can call if, e.g., you explicitly create a `matplotlib.pyplot.Figure`.

Comment: You are correct, figsize and multiply barh height by the number of Y axis values